# Delete Message From Inbox

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, many-to-many, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 - Code First and I have a many to many relationship between my `User` and `Message` entities. The relationship is mapped through another entity `UserMessage`. The messaging system I've implemented resembled that of Gmail, which means messages are "threads" where replies of a message are shown along the initial message.

Now I'm trying to delete a message from a user's inbox, but I do not want it to end up being deleted from the database because the other user might not choose to delete the message from his/her inbox. Unfortunately, my code is throwing the following exception:

> A relationship from the
>   'UserMessage_Receiver' AssociationSet
>   is in the 'Deleted' state. Given
>   multiplicity constraints, a
>   corresponding
>   'UserMessage_Receiver_Source' must
>   also in the 'Deleted' state.

Here's the code involved:

```
public class UserMessage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastViewed { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }

    public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }
    public virtual User Receiver { get; set; }
}

    public void DeleteFromInbox(int messageId, User user)
    {
        var message = _repository.First<UserMessage>(c=>c.Message.Id.Equals(messageId));
        var replies = GetReplies(user, messageId);
        foreach (var reply in replies)
        {
            if (user.ReceivedMessages.Contains(reply))
            {
                user.ReceivedMessages.Remove(reply);
                reply.Receiver = null;
            }
            if (user.SentMessages.Contains(reply))
            {
                user.SentMessages.Remove(reply);
                reply.Sender = null;
            }
        }
        message.Receiver = null;
        user.ReceivedMessages.Remove(message);
    }
```

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: `var` is nice if you see what result type is used from the right part of assignment but in case of `GetReplies` we don't know what type did you return and what your `foreach` is removing.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: It is returning an `IList<UserMessage>` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing entity from navigation property will not mark it as deleted. It will only remove relation - that mean that FK in `UserMessage` will be set to null and if it is not nullable you will get your exception. You must do something like:

```
    foreach (var reply in replies)
    {
        if (user.ReceivedMessages.Contains(reply))
        {
            user.ReceivedMessages.Remove(reply);
            reply.Receiver = null;
        }

        if (user.SentMessages.Contains(reply))
        {
            user.SentMessages.Remove(reply);
            reply.Sender = null;
        }

        _repository.Delete(reply);
    }
```

Edit:

The mentioned code deletes `UserMessage` - not `Message`. As I think about your model your new problem is obvious. Your first exception was caused by multiplicity constraints on the `UserMessage` entity - `Receiver` is mandatory so you cannot remove relation to receiver without removing whole `UserMessage` but once you remove `UserMessage` (and there is no other receiver of the message) it will remove it from sender as well.

Your model is wrong. Even if you make `Receiver` optional it will result in `UserMessage` instances without receiver and unless you store receiver list somewhere else you will lost information about one of original receivers (when sender open the message again from his outbox he will most probably not see the receiver).

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Shouldn't I delete the message itself as well? When I did that it solved the problem, but a new problem arose. When I logged in with the other user (who first sent the message), I got a null object reference exception... That's what I was trying to avoid...

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: So do I have to re-model the whole thing or would adding "ReceiverName" to the UserMessage solve the problem? Also, can I make the Receiver optional via DataAnnotations or do I need to use fluent configuration?

Comment: I would separate message information and inbox information. Move sender from `UserMessage` to `Message` and keep all receiver names as string field in message. Your `UserMessage` will be only for modelling inbox of single user. If you remove the message from the user you will delete this instance but real message will be still untouched.

Comment: I see. But in this case, how would EF know that it should use UserMessage to map the relationship and not create another table on its own? Do I need to some configurations or is EF smart enough to figure it out?

Comment: Try it and you will see. It should use your `UserMessage` entity.